# How to prevent Command+Option+M from minimizing Safari

Tags: macos, safari, google-docs

In version 10.0 Safari started responding to Command+Option+M shortcut along with standard Command+M. This causes issues in Google Docs as there Command+Option+M means "Add comment". How to fix that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this default shortcut at: System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > [+]

Then follow this:

- Application: “Safari”
- Menu Title: “Minimize All”
- Set whatever keyboard shortcut you’d rather it be besides the default of ⌘M

Comment: FYI: "Minimize All" not "Minimize" is a good and important distinction. To see what's up, in Safari, click "Window" and then toggle `option` back and forth.

Comment: Just to clarify, since it was unclear to me, if you use a localized version of Safari (foreign language), follow Paul's advice, open the Window (or it's equivalent) dropdown menu and press `option` to see the localized name of the "... All" variant